# How do I go about plotting the decision boundaries decided by my trained kNN?

Tags: python, machine-learning, knn

As of now I have split the Iris dataset into training, value and test sets.
I have trained knn for values 1,5,10,15,20,30 and found the training accuracy.
What I want now is to plot the decision boundaries.

I have found some examples but am not sure how to implement my code into this so that it plots my data.
Example code that does what I want to do:

```
#Calculate min, max and limits  
x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h), np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))

# predict class using data and kNN classifier
Z = knn.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])


# Put the result into a color plot
Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
plt.figure()
plt.pcolormesh(xx, yy, Z, cmap=cmap_light, shading='auto')

# Plot
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=Y, cmap=cmap_bold)
plt.xlim(xx.min(), xx.max())
plt.ylim(yy.min(), yy.max())
plt.title("3-Class classification (k = %i)" % n_neighbors)
plt.show()
```

The code I want to implement into this so that it shows my data:

```
X = iris.data[:, :2]
Y = iris.target

X_train, X_val_test, Y_train, Y_val_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=.3, shuffle=True,
                                                            random_state=666)  

X_val, X_test, Y_val, Y_test = train_test_split(X_val_test, Y_val_test, test_size=.5, shuffle=True,
                                                random_state=221)  
# Store number of datapoints in each dataset:
N_train = len(Y_train)
N_val = len(Y_val)
N_test = len(Y_test)
print("Datapoints used for training:   ", N_train)
print("Datapoints used for validation: ", N_val)
print("Datapoints used for testing :   ", N_test)
# 70% - 30% - 30% train / val / test ratio

h = .02  # step size in the mesh

# Create color maps
cmap_light = ListedColormap(['#FFAAAA', '#AAFFAA', '#00AAFF'])
cmap_bold = ListedColormap(['#FF0000', '#00FF00', '#00AAFF'])


# Try K = 1, 5, 10, 15, 20 and 30 - And record testing accuracy
k_list = [1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 30]
scores = []

for k in k_list:
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k)
    knn.fit(X_train, Y_train)
    Y_pred = knn.predict(X_test)
    scores.append(metrics.accuracy_score(Y_test, Y_pred))
```